# Nodejs creating session on every request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

We are creating a nodejs application where i need to maintain sessions. We are using express to maintain node variables. But the problem is Whenever we are hitting a new service, a new session is getting created.

app.js file look like this

```js
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

 module.exports = function Sessions(url, secret) {
   var store = new RedisStore({ url: url });
   var session = session({
  secret: 'dfsdfdff',
  store: 'test',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
   });

   return session;
 };
```

```
var express = require('express');
var session  = require('express-session');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var path = require('path');
var Q = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require("formidable");
var util = require('util');
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');
var users = require('./routes/language');
var user_auth = require('./routes/auth');
```

auth.js file look like this

```js
exports.generateToken = function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
    page_title: 'PEN_V4'});
    var sess = req.session;
    sess.user_id = 'Hello1';
    console.log('Hello 1============');
    console.log(sess.user_id);
    console.log('session*****************************============');
    console.log(sess);
    res.end();

}
exports.myToken = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log('session============');
    console.log('session*****************************============');
    res.end();
}
```

```js
 app.configure(function() {
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.methodOverride());
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
        app.use(express.cookieParser());
        app.use(express.session({
            secret: 'alessios',
            store: MemStore({
                reapInterval: 60000 * 10
            }),
   cookie :{httpOnly: true}
        }));
    });
```

then from index.html we are calling api's myToken and generateToken. But both apis are showing different sessions. Can any please guide us something regarding what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Please post how you initialize the session. Also please post the headers sent from express.

Comment: added the headers and intialization method

Comment: If I run `curl -v http://localhost:3000/` I get this answer in the headers: `set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AvrxyuLkQ8JHDS7O5kZ9vL9jU0TOPaGip.K3zFYVzopymsz5eXPMEN5pTlaKBHgZso3DJu3EidmW8; Path=/; HttpOnly`. Please post confirmation that set-cookie header is sent from your app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the `express-session` middleware? Just require the package is not enough, you need to use it, like this:

```
const session = require('express-session');    
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore(config.redis),
  secret: 'w5qTAcEMgNeNzrPg',
  proxy: true,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

(In this example, I use Redis session store)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the built in bodyParser and cookieParser, which are only included in Express versions before 4.x, I conclude that you are using an outdated version of Express. Your problem could possibly be solved by upgrading Express (information on upgrading from 3.x to 4.x: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/express-3-to-4-migration-guide/)

There seems to be a problem with the set-cookie header when setting multiple cookies and therefore the session-cookie isn't set on the first request (or every other request where another cookie should be set). Is this the case in your complete setup?

For further information on the issue and a possible fix, please read the following answer I gave to another question: [Express-session with passport.js multiple cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112592/express-session-with-passport-js-multiple-cookies/36310764#36310764)

Comment: add code instead of link for better explanation of answer.

Comment: I don't really see a reason to post the exact same code and explanation twice as this wouldn't make the explanation itself "better". Furthermore @Sumeet didn't clarify if multiple cookies are set in his setup and therefore it is unclear if it is the real problem. If you follow the second link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112592/express-session-with-passport-js-multiple-cookies/36310764#36310764) you will find one code example showing the problem (including the generated headers) and the code to fix the issue if upgrading isn't possible.